# Using :hover pseudo class in nested lists

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to get the effect of adding certain extra values to list items when they are hovered. I am very close, but when using nested lists, the parent thinks it's hovered as well as the child.

This is my simple test case. The desired result is that each item will show the span if, and only if, it is hovered. Hovering over 'Test 5.3' should NOT result in 'Test 5' having the span shown.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing list :)</title>
<style type="text/css">
li span {
    visibility: hidden;
}
li:hover > span {
    visibility: visible;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
    <li>Test 1<span> - Edit</span></li>
    <li>Test 2<span> - Edit</span></li>
    <li>Test 3<span> - Edit</span></li>
    <li>Test 4<span> - Edit</span></li>
    <li>Test 5<span> - Edit</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Test 5.1<span> - Edit</span></li>
            <li>Test 5.2<span> - Edit</span></li>
            <li>Test 5.3<span> - Edit</span></li>
            <li>Test 5.4<span> - Edit</span></li>
            <li>Test 5.5<span> - Edit</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Test 6<span> - Edit</span></li>
    <li>Test 7<span> - Edit</span></li>
    <li>Test 8<span> - Edit</span></li>
    <li>Test 9<span> - Edit</span></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Link to version online to save you copying out the above: [test.html](http://matdiesel.leadhoster.com/test.html)

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that this is possible with CSS if the maximal depth is unknown. I hope somebody (maybe even myself) can prove me wrong.

Comment: So... any browser compatibility requirements? (I have no solution, I'm just wondering.) @thirtydot: I hope so too.

Comment: @thirtydot, I hope so too. As it happens I do know the maximum depth, but I was hoping I wouldn't need to resort to that, as it is in double figures.

Comment: @BoltClock, Well... Yes and no. As with all things I would like it to work in all browsers, but it's ultimate use will be mostly for me, using chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**See:** http://jsbin.com/ihole5/3/

I cheated and changed your HTML, from:

```
<li>Test 1<span> - Edit</span></li>
```

to include an extra wrapping `span`: *(this has subtly changed from my original answer)*

```
<li><span>Test 1<span> - Edit</span></span></li>
```

The CSS is simple this time:

```
li > span > span {
    visibility: hidden;
}
li > span:hover > span {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Well, the cursor can't reach the `span` that appears on hover without leaving the other `span` and making it disappear. And I do think that "Edit" is supposed to be clickable.

Comment: That's fantastic. Since the above example is oversimplified, this actually works very well as the spans have a class, so I don't need :last-of-type. Furthermore there is already an element where you added the new span, so that works great as well.

Comment: @BoltClock: Oops! I'm fixing it up.

Comment: I fixed it by doing [this](http://matdiesel.leadhoster.com/test2.html). But your method of making the spans nested is much better.

Comment: @Mat: See the updated version, you can actually click "Edit" this time! Hopefully that's still acceptable.

Comment: Lovely. I was trying not to change the HTML and all I could come up with was a `span:not(:only-child)` and some opacity tricks, and still get some glitches.

Comment: @BoltClock: Thanks. I'm not convinced it *was* possible with the original HTML.

Comment: @thirtydot: I knew from the get-go that I couldn't, but being the masochist I am, I spent half an hour proving myself right.

Comment: @thirtydot and @BoltClock, in the end it was actually far easier. I had simplified the html to be as simple as possible, when in actual fact it was much more like what thirtydot ended up with. Thanks both of you.

Answer (score -1):

You have a misunderstanding about how :hover works.  It applies to all the parents of an element too - i.e. you can't hover over the internal `li` without also hovering over its parent `ul`, and that parents `li`, `ul`, all the way up to `body`.

Comment: I understand that :) And even if I didn't, that's the behaviour I have seen and want to avoid. I'm not asking "What am I doing wrong?" or "Why doesn't :hover work like I expect?", I'm asking "What workaround is there?"